# Car stalling while driving and other related? Issues

Tags: starting, stall, citroen

New to forums so please be gentle

I am having intermittent issues with our 2007 Citroen C4 Grand Piccasso and am hoping to narrow it down slightly as I understand this could be any number of issues or potentially several seperate issues...

Symptoms are as follows:

Has cut out several times now whilst driving, doesn’t appear to be fuel related as it doesn’t sputter etc, just engine off, once I didn’t even notice it had stalled for a few seconds. After cutout sometimes it restarts immediately, other times the is one click noise on turning ingnition then nothing, and other times (like today) the starter cranks continually but will not start.

I have noticed that on all occasions that this has happened the car has started successfully after a period of time (cooled down?) and driving is fine until the next time...

I have been told it could be Coil, ignition switch, faulty alternator, battery (I have put a new battery in now with no change) fuel pump, ECU computer, wiring harness. I am hoping to narrow down a bit or at least get the most likely one from the symptoms as I can’t do any of work myself and can’t afford to take to the dealer

Thanks in advance

Comment: When it stalls, are there dash warning lights lit?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: @handyhowie, I don’t think so, I didn’t notice any come on but can’t be 100%. I will take note when it happens again to make sure they didn’t

Comment: No lights could indicate a total electrical power failure.  So this is important information.